# Understanding dual spaces and Riesz's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is this a proper statement for the Dual space of a Hilbert space?

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. The set of all continuous bounded linear maps, $\mathcal{L}(H,\mathbb{R})$,  is called the dual space.

I also am trying to understand [Riesz's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem)

This is what I believe the theorem is saying:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\varphi\in \mathcal{L}(H,\mathbb{R})$. Then there exists a unique $y\in H$ such that $\varphi(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$ for all $x\in H$.

Comment: In fact, this assignment shows that $H\cong\mathcal{L}(H,\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you wrote is essentially correct.

Note that the field can be the complex numbers too, then the inner product will be sesquilinear instead of bilinear.

To elaborate more, the inner product $(x,y)=l(x)$ (for fixed $y$) is a linear functional.
It is also bounded by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $|l(x)|=|(x,y)|\leq\|y\|\|x\|$.

What the Riesz representation theorem says is that conversely, any bounded linear functional $l(x)$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is of the form $l(x)=(x,y)$ for fixed $y\in H$. This is kind of surprising (at least to me).